# Probability that $x$ elements belong to a group, $y$ to a second group and $z$ to a third one

Tags: probability

I have been trying to solve a problem that goes like this:

After a software update, it is estimated that 10% of games will need complete modification of the code base, 60% won't need any modification and 30% will need only partial modification. What is the probability that out of 6 games, 2 will need complete modification, 1 will not need any modifications and 3 will need only partial modification?

I tried using a probabilistic model to approach this, yet it doesn't seem to fit any. A solution I thought of was to denote the games as $G_1,...,G_6$ and assign to each one a probability, such that 1 needs no modifications and 2 need complete modifications, take that probability, and then multiply with the number of permutations, so in the end I got to $6! \cdot (0.6 \cdot 0.1^{2} \cdot 0.3^{3})$. I think this is correct, but I'm not sure. Or, is there a better, more intuitive solution? Or one that uses a probabilistic model?

Comment: **Multinomial distribution.** You don't explicitly mention how many need partial modification. Hard to say without seeing your reasoning and work. Maybe ${6\choose 2,1,3}(.1)^2(.6)(.3)^3,$ where the multinomial coefficient is $\frac{6!}{2!\cdot 1!\cdot 3!}.$

Comment: @BruceET it's 3 as well for that, the problem meant exactly 2 need complete modification and exactly 1 doesn't need any, so the rest of 3 will need partial. Sorry for that missing part, I will address it.

Comment: @BruceET although yes, that would be the coefficient. I took too many ways and repeated a lot of them by just using $6!$, as their order wouldn't matter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The number of possible orders does affect the probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After a software update, it is estimated that 10% of games will need complete modification of the code base, 60% won't need any modification and 30% will need only partial modification. What is the probability that out of 6 games, 2 will need complete modification and 1 will not need any modifications?

Chances that games 1 and 2 need complete modification, game 3 doesn't need any modification and games 4 through 6 need partial modification is

$$P = (0.1)^2 \times (0.6) \times (0.3)^3.$$

The number of ways that the above scenario can unfold is

$$T = \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{1}.$$

Final Answer:

$$P \times T.$$

Comment: That's right, thank you, I haven't realized I was taking way too many possibilities using permutations.